Question on the proof of Engel's Theorem step 1 in book Introduction to Lie Algebras
I am reading chapter 6.1 Engle's Theorem of book "Introduction to Lie Algebras" by Karin Erdmann and Mark J. Wildon, and have a question on Step 1 of the Proof for Proposition 6.2.
It says that "We claim that A is an ideal of L and that dim A = dim L - 1". My question is that: why is this claim valid, why the the ideal of L (a maximal Lie subalgebra) has dimension dim L - 1?
It makes sense that L contains some subalgebra A that could be an ideal. Somehow I don't see the connection of being an ideal with the claim on dimension.

Those are two separate claims both of which they prove later. In fact they are simply stating what they plan to show in the proof.
They show that $\tilde{A} = A \oplus \mathrm{Span}\{y\}$ is a larger subalgebra for some $y$ and since $A$ is maximal $\tilde{A} = L$ so that $\dim A = \dim L -1$ and moreover they show $A$ is an ideal of $\tilde{A} = L$.

Thanks for replying and the explanation. I understand the first paragraph proved homomorphism of $\phi$,  and then the following paragraph proved $\phi(a)$ nilpotent. I was stuck then on the $\phi(a)(y + A) = [a, y] + A =  0$ for all $a \in A$. Where did that come from?

Ah I see, it's all inductive. dim 1 is trivial. The rest is by induction. take assumption of dim L  - 1, proof is only needed for dim L - 1 -> dim L.
